# Who owned the ship Ensayo, and what were they doing near Baja California in 1842?

Tags: 19th-century, spain, age-of-sail, philippines, piracy

According to Plummer's *The Shogun's Reluctant Ambassadors*, in 1842, sea drifters from the *Eijū-maru* were picked up and  by the *Ensayo*, a "Spanish pirate ship" with a Philippine crew. It was "carrying illegal goods between Spain or Mexico and Manila," and "[b]ecause it was on a 'wanted list', it could not enter any harbors freely." The Japanese men were treated badly and forced ashore on a beach in Baja California.

I found the description confusing. Of Pacific ports, only the Philippines were still Spanish. The Manila galleon system had been over for decades. During Mexico's first twenty years of independence, as far as I know, it didn't trade with East Asia. The Spanish were a minor presence in the Pacific even when they controlled a lot of its coastline.

Who owned *Ensayo* and what was it up to?

Comment: According to Del tratado al tratado. 120 años de relaciones entre Japón y México by Aurelio Asiain, 2008 (p. 46), the Ensayo didn't commit piracy but smuggling. She smuggled goods from and to Mexico. Adiain's source seems to be Sano, Yoshikazu, Vida en México de trece náufragos japoneses, 1842.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos - Any way you could see your way to expanding that to an answer? It probably wouldn't take much, as it seems like you already put in enough research for it to be one. You ought to reap the reward for that work, and Aaron may eventually even want to accept it.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't have access to either of those books and I can't quote more. I just  have that reference. That is why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @AlbertoYagos - I can't always speak for all our voters, but I for one would consider what you have there acceptable, with perhaps a GoodReads link to the book in question, and an admission that you are working from memory.

Comment: I had "Vida en México de trece náufragos japoneses" in my hands, but forgot to look for this point!!

Comment: @AlbertoYagos: I concur with T.E.D.'s view.